# Why is there no response when i call the function in the if statement?

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I'm new to python and my first project is to create a GUI app with a few buttons to play songs. The problem is in the if statement, VLC will not play the file no matter what i do. This if statement worked in another program only running in the Terminal.

```
import vlc

import easygui 

x = easygui.buttonbox(choices=("x","y","z"))

if x == "y":

    p = vlc.MediaPlayer("/directory/to/mp3/file")
    p.play()
```

Comment: Can you debug your code so check if it executes `p.play` or not?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation for easygui it appears that the choices for a buttonbox are stored as a list and not as a tuple. Try `easygui.buttonbox(choice=["x","y","z"])` instead.